# explain how to use trashItemAtURL method in file management iOS

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

I'm sunil. I'm trying to move a text file to trash through programming. Here the code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
//        - (BOOL)trashItemAtURL:(NSURL *)url resultingItemURL:(NSURL **)outResultingURL error:(NSError **)error NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_8);

NSFileManager * aFM = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL * trash;
NSError * error;

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/SunilKumar/Desktop/samResTemp/samResources.text"];

NSLog(@"trashItemAtURL %hhd",[aFM trashItemAtURL:url resultingItemURL:&trash error:&error]);

}
return 0;
}
```

but I'm getting output as "trashItemAtURL 0"

please help me in doing this. Thank U in Advance

Answer (score 1):

For an URL in the file system (scheme `file://`) you have to use the `fileURLWithPath:` initializer

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/SunilKumar/Desktop/samResTemp/samResources.text"];
```

the `URLWithString` initializer is for URL with a different scheme like `http://` or `ftp://`

However to use the `URLWithString` initializer with a file path the scheme must be included in the string

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/SunilKumar/Desktop/samResTemp/samResources.text"];
```